# I get a compile error: variable not defined in backend, same code works in an exact copy on frontend

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was following a guide on how to make a basic login form in access vba, however today when i started up my work pc, the login doesn't seem to be working at all in my back end (from which i originally exported the login form to my front end). It gave me a "User defined type not defined" error pointing to "`Private Sub btnLogin_Click()`" but that's no longer the case, now it randomly without making any changes is giving me a "compile error: variable not defined" pointing to "`Private Sub btnLogin_Click()`" and highlighting "`dbOpenSnapshot`"

here's the entire code from my backend file which gives me the error

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("BElogon", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "logon_user='" & Me.txtboxname & "'"

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    Me.txtwrongname.Visible = True
    Me.txtboxname.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.txtwrongname.Visible = False


If rs!logon_pass <> Me.txtboxpass Then
    Me.txtwrongpass.Visible = True
    Me.txtboxpass.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.txtwrongpass.Visible = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "FEindex"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

and here's the version in my front end which works flawlessly

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("BElogon", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "logon_user='" & Me.txtboxname & "'"

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    Me.txtwrongname.Visible = True
    Me.txtboxname.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.txtwrongname.Visible = False


If rs!logon_pass <> Me.txtboxpass Then
    Me.txtwrongpass.Visible = True
    Me.txtboxpass.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Me.txtwrongpass.Visible = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "FEindex"
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

End Sub
```

i have found that it might be a missing reference however my front end doesn't have them enabled either and it works, so i'm just trying to understand this..

Comment: Try to **de**compile the database (use Microsoft Access command line parameter `/decompile`).

Comment: Could you maybe please clarify a bit on this?

Comment: I'm unable to see what has actually happened after launching accesss /decompile through Run and then opening a DB as reccommended through some other posts about this.

Comment: A backend is not for running code, it is for data (tables) only. So, remove any code from the backend and continue using the frontend for user access.

Answer (score 0):

If the suggestions to Decompile the database didn't work, it may be the use of `dbOpenSnapshot` or `dbReadOnly`. Instead, try:

```
Set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("BElogon")
```

Also, rather than opening the table with all records selected, and then trying to find a match, it is faster to open a recordset that is already filtered:

```
Set rs=CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT logon_pass FROM BElogon WHERE logon_user='" & Me!txtboxname & "'")
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then    ' have found a matching user
    If rs!logon_pass<>Me!txtboxpass Then    ' password supplied does not match that stored for the user

    End If
Else    '   user name not found

End If
```

Regards,